# how do i show the options in a select box when i tab into the box?

Tags: javascript, html, select, onfocus

I am building an application and have a page with a bunch of select boxes where the user must set different options...

How do i show all the options that are available when the user tabs into the box? Currently i can tab into the box and start typing and it will search through the options, but it does not show the available ones.

Is there a javascript solution for this?
I am using firefox.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Im sure I am missing something really simple... But i cant seem to figure it out..

Comment: A user can use the up and down arrow keys to browse through the list. But I don't know of any method that opens the list; the non-standard [`element.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click) is not available for `select` elements.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. There just isn't any javascript to open a select box. `element.click()` would probably work if it was available, but as has been said, it's not, and it's not very compatible anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you out - http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/gr/column5/ - Refer to the 'AutoComplete.prototype.onchange = function()' It seems to me if you called this (Customized to your uses of course) on the gotfocus event it should do what you want it to. Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't dealing with plain HTML `select` boxes, but with custom-made autocomplete input.

Comment: @Cshantz My bad, I thought you'd be able to pass it a select box as the oText object